# choking.. client specific

Tags: tension, creak

Ive always gotten away with using and processing a bit of leather creaks for that tight feeling of something around your throat. I usually get great responses, but right now I have a client that isnt satisfied with any throat choking im delivering him. I recorded cabbage, used certain ropes, and he can tell when its leather or rubber and it bugs him. So in return its bugging me!!! Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a really quiet mic and a really quiet room? I would recommend experimenting with other items that are fibrous, like rope — something you can stretch or bend that mimics the sound of muscles and cartilage collapsing in the neck and throat. Some things that come to mind:

- celery ... bend it enough so that it flexes but doesn't break
- a bell pepper ... try squeezing it in your hand, then cut it into large chunks and and bend them slowly
- find a small piece of fabric (better yet, a fabric sack) and fill it with items that grind and crunch... maybe granola cereal, small rocks, small twigs... and squeeze it all together in the fabric bag. Maybe try dunking the whole thing in water and repeat.

Combining these with elements of skin-on-skin and maybe a few larger crunch sounds and see how it works.

Let us know how it goes! 
~Matt

Comment: Thanks, great ideas! Ill do the celery tomorrow. I also like the cloth sack I could see how that would work. Thanks again stay tuned.

Answer (score 2):

Does the client specifically want the sound of the physical choking object? Remember that sound design is all about creating and/or supporting perspective. Maybe you'd be better served by focusing on the human/animal side of choking (gasps, gurgles, snorts, etc.).

If the client does want that object sound, another item you could try is a loosely woven wicker basket or bunching up and twisting some individual reeds.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome ideas. If I have trouble with the literal sounds, I try the metaphorical/dramatic. You could avoid the literal sounds altogether. Maybe you could focus your thoughts on the reason for choking. Who is the protagonist and what do they have to lose? Whatever the motivation is, identify that, record it, and play with that sound.

Answer (score 0):

use contact mics (piezos) and sink them in dense foam... cheap